# Can't use InsertOnSubmit method when inserting in database LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, insert

There's an error when I write this code and says `'object' does not contain a definition for 'InsertOnSubmit' and no extension method like it`. Here's my code.

```
LoginDBDataContext dc = new LoginDBDataContext(conn);
Student_User su = new Student_User();
int user = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtUser.Text);
string pass = txtPassword.Text;
su.Student_Number = user;
su.Password = pass;
su.Lock_Try = 0;
su.Lock_Date = DateTime.Now;
su.Forgot_Password = 0;
dc.Student_User.InsertOnSubmit(su);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979398/ling-to-sql-mydatacontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-insertonsubmit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `dc.Student_User.InsertOnSubmit(su);` with `dc.Student_Users.InsertOnSubmit(su);` or wtever your name is for `DbSet<Student_User>` in your dbModel. 
`dc.Student_Users.InsertOnSubmit(su);`because appending `s` to entity is normal covention.